# For $f\in \mathrm{End}_{\mathrm{End}_R (M)}(M)$ and $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}\subset M$ exists $r\in R$ such that $f(x_i)=r\cdot x_i, \, i=1,\ldots, n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

The exercise is as follows:

Let $R$ be an unitary ring (not necessarily commutative), $M$ a semisimple $R$-module.

Let $S=\mathrm{End}_R(M)$, so $M$ is an $S$-module with $T\cdot m=T(m)$, for $T\in S, m\in M$. Let $E=\mathrm{End}_S(M)$, $M$ is an $E$-module similarly.

(a) Prove that $N\subset M$ is an $R$-submodule of $M$ if and only if $N\subset M$ is an $E$-submodule of $M$.

(b) Prove that for all $f\in \mathrm{End}_S(M)$ and for all $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}\subset M$ exists $r\in R$ such that $f(x_i)=r\cdot x_i, \, i=1,\ldots, n$.

I managed to do (a) but I cannot prove (b).

I noted that if $x\in M$ and $f\in \mathrm{End}_S(M)$, as $Rx$ is an $R$-submodule of $M$, by part (a) $Rx$ is an $E$-submodule of $M$ then $f(Rx)\subset Rx$ therefore $f(x)=r\cdot x$ with $r\in R$. With this observation, for $x_i$ we can do the same, but how can I get the same $r$ for all $x_i$?

Can you suggest me any ideas to finish? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you prove it if $M$ is simple?

Comment: Mmm, I think an argument like this: If $M$ is simple, $M\cong Rx$ for some $x\in M$. Then for $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}\subset M$ (not all 0), we have that $Rx_1+\cdots+Rx_n$ is an $R$-submodule so $Rx_1+\dots+R x_n=Rx$ then $x_i=r_i x$, so $f(x_i)=f(r_i x)=r_i f(x)=r_i r x$, and I would like to this be $r r_i x=r x_i$, but $r_i$ does not necessarily commute with $r$ so I stuck. Does your hint go in this way?

Comment: It sounds weird but for $f \in End_S(M)$, it is not necessarily true that $f(rx) = rf(x)$ for $r\in R, x \in M$. Maybe consider the case of $R$ a (non-commutative) skew field first, and pay close attention to whether one multiplies from the left or right.

Comment: Does "for $f\in \mathrm{End}_S(M)$, it is not necessarily true that $f(rx)=rf(x)$ for $r\in R,x\in M$." contradicts (a)?

Comment: No it does not contradict (a). As said, look at a basic but instructive case like $R$ being the quaternions and $M$ being the one-dimensional left vector space over it.